# API verbs for an interruptible operation

Tags: .net, api, asynchronous

I have a long running task as part of my application. The task can be started, paused, resumed, and cancelled. I'm trying to find the best interface for these operations.

Two seem clear: `Pause` and `Cancel`. This leaves the start and resume operations. I could include both `Start` and `Resume`. This has the downside of either requiring the API consumer to check the state before starting/resuming the operation to call the right method, or making the methods aliases of each other. I'm thinking one possibility is using *either* Start or Resume, but I don't know which one is the most appropriate.

Does anyone have any examples in the .NET Framework of such behavior? I prefer to follow established patterns whenever they are available.

**Edit:** The most similar case I found so far is from the Workflow library. [`WorkflowInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms611690.aspx) has the methods:

- Abort
- Start
- Suspend
- Resume
- Terminate

Comment: How about 'Onward' or 'TallyHo'? Hmmm, maybe not... :)

Answer (score 0):

"Run" might capture both "Start" and "Resume" - or possibly "Go"?

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing more about what exactly you're doing, I would recommend using something akin to a factory when doing something like this, separating the task from the control. For instance:

```
public class Task
{
    public TaskController Start()
    {
        TaskController controller = new TaskController(this);

        ... // start the task

        return controller;
    }
}

public class TaskController
{
    private Task task;

    internal TaskController(Task task)
    {
        this.task = task;
    }

    public void Pause() { ... }
    public void Resume() { ... }
    public void Cancel() { ... }
}
```

In reality, it depends on what you're doing as to whether or not this is appropriate (for instance, this approach would--conceivably--allow you to spawn multiple instances of the task running in parallel; I have no idea if that's appropriate).

`Start` and `Resume` are pretty standard terms. If you're looking to include only *one of those*, I'd choose start. If you're looking for a more suitable term that can serve both purposes, I'd choose something like `Run` (since both `Start` and `Resume` imply something about the state of the task...`Resume` especially...and IMO `Run` conveys slightly less than `Start`).

Comment: In theory, this could apply to any long running operation.

Answer (score 0):

The interface seems very much like that for a Windows Service.  The [ServiceController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller_methods.aspx) class has Start/Stop/Pause/Continue for it's methods.  I could see combining the Start/Continue methods into one, say Run, but then you'd have to handle the difference internally.  You might want to consider how you would "reset" the service from a Paused state.  If you only had Run, then you'd need to do Stop/Run.  Start might automatically reset the state removing the need in this case.  I'd examine the use cases and design it from the perspective of the normal path through those.